# Extra argument 'selector' in call error

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

func ChangePage()
{
    NSLog("Hej")
}

var timers = NSTimer(NSTimeInterval(0.5), target:self, selector: "ChangePage", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

}

I get the following error from Xcode 6:
Extra Argument 'selector' in call

I've tried several configurations, does it have something to do with where in the code it's placed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use:

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: "changePage", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

This returns a timer that is already added to the run loop and fires automatically.

To stop the timer to fire, you must invalidate it like this

```
timer.invalidate()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add timeInterval in the constructor like:

```
NSTimer(timeInterval: NSTimeInterval(0.5), target:self, selector: "ChangePage", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

And yes, it does matter where you put. The problem is, that timers is a property, and it is created before the initialization. So when it is created, self is not existing, but you refer to it, and that causes the problem.

Comment: It solved the error message, but doesn't looks like it's running. I placed the var timers = NSTimer(..... code in viewDidLoad()
And the func. is in same viewController though outside viewDidLoad.
Do you have a hint?

Comment: I think you should add the timer with the addTimer:forMode to the runloop, or instantiate the timer as the other answer suggests.